# Send Textframe to WebSocket echo-server

Tags: c++, tcp, websocket, binary, binary-data

I am writing a WebSocket implementation in C++. It is almost finished now and I wanted to test it against this [WebSocket echo-server](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html). First, I'm connecting to it and `Upgrade` to WebSocket-Protocol in the HTTP-Handshake.

Then I send a Text-Frame with "This is a test" as content. This is what my program sends:

```
FRRR-OP- M-LENGTH MASK-KEY
10000001 10001110 00000100 

MASK-KEY MASK-KEY MASK-KEY
01000101 11010000 01101011 

--DATA-- --DATA-- --DATA--
01010000 00101101 10111001 

--DATA-- --DATA-- --DATA--
00011000 00100100 00101100 

--DATA-- --DATA-- --DATA--
10100011 01001011 01100101 

--DATA-- --DATA-- --DATA--
01100101 10000100 00001110 

--DATA-- --DATA--
01110111 00110001
```

---

I'll explain the letters quickly:

- **F**: *Indicates that this is the final fragment in a message* (quote RFC6455)
- **RRR**: RSV1, RSV2, RSV3. Always 0, unless an extension is used.
- **-OP-**: The Op-Code. Op-Code 1 = Text Message
- **M**: Indicates if the data is masked or not. 1 = it is masked.
- **-LENGTH**: The length in bytes of the data (**excluding** the MASK-KEY).
- **MASK-KEY**: The Key that was used to encrypt the data. Always 4 Bytes long.

From [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.3)

> To    convert masked data into unmasked data, or vice versa, the
> following    algorithm is applied.  The same algorithm applies
> regardless of the    direction of the translation, e.g., the same
> steps are applied to    mask the data as to unmask the data.
>
> Octet i of the transformed data ("transformed-octet-i") is the XOR
> of    octet i of the original data ("original-octet-i") with octet at
> index    i modulo 4 of the masking key ("masking-key-octet-j"):
>
> ```
>  j                   = i MOD 4
>  transformed-octet-i = original-octet-i XOR masking-key-octet-j
> ```

- **Data**: The encrypted data ("This is a Test")

---

After sending this frame, it takes the *echo-server* very long to respond (*~45 seconds*), and this is the data I get:

```
FRRR-OP- M-LENGTH --DATA--
10000001 00001110 01010100

--DATA-- --DATA-- --DATA-- 
01101000 01101001 01110011

--DATA-- --DATA-- --DATA-- 
00100000 01101001 01110011

--DATA-- --DATA-- --DATA-- 
00100000 01100001 00100000

--DATA-- --DATA-- --DATA-- 
01010100 01100101 01110011

--DATA-- --DATA-- --DATA-- 
01110100 10001001 00000000
```

Converting the data to string results in this.

```
This is a Test&#8240;
```

So something is going wrong here. It can't be a wrong OP-Code, as the server responds. It can't be wrong encryption, because the server can decrypt the data. The length is also not wrong how you can see. However, it is strange that the server takes very long to respond. It seems like it is waiting for more data to come.

Answer (score 0):

The last two bytes (`10001001`, `00000000`) are a [ping frame](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) with no payload.